# Mysql query to pull out newest row and not showing others with the same id

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a mysql query.

I have three tables:

- Members(id,name,company)
- questions(id,question)
- questionanswerxref(id,userid,questionid,answer)

When the member answers pre defined questions it is inserted into the questionanswerxref table. They end up answering the same questions multiple times as situations change and time goes on. I need to run a query that will give me each question and the newest answer for a specific member ( I add in the memberid depending who is signed in ).

As of now I have the following, but I have tried a couple variations of it If they have not answered a question I do want to show it with no answer as well.

```
SELECT MAX( qq.id ) , coalesce( qq.answer, '' ) AS answer, q.question
FROM `questionanswerxref` qq
LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.id = qq.questionid
WHERE qq.userid = ".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."
GROUP BY qq.id,q.id
ORDER BY q.id"
```

another version of that is..

```
select q.id,q.question, coalesce(qq.answer,'') as answer from questions q
left join questionanswerxref qq on q.id = qq.questionid AND qq.userid = ".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."
group by q.id,qq.id
```

I keep getting the questions multiple times. So if they answer the same question 4 times it shows each one. I only want the last answer they submitted.

Seems like it should be easy but im stumped.

Comment: If they answer the same question 4 times, what decides which is "newest"? You don't have a date or time value to indicate when it was answered. How do you know what is "the last answer"? Can you [edit] to provide a small sample of the data and the results you'd like to get from that sample data?

Comment: Hi @KenWhite Terje D answered my question with a query that worked but since you took the time to respond I wanted to answer. Each time they answer the ID increments and is unique so that is what I use to see what the newest is. Thats why grabbing MAX(ID) works. I appreciate you responding though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your queries is that you group by questionanswerxref.id, thus in fact not grouping at all since id probably is a primary key in this table.

Another problem is that you are selecting fields that are neither aggregate functions nor mention in the `group by` clause`, which gives undetermined results or errors, depending on the dbms.

Assuming that you want the answers with the highest id for each user and answer,
you can use a subquery grouping by userid and questionid to find the id's of the latest answers, and then join this to the questions and the answers:

```
SELECT q.id, q.question, coalesce(qq.answer,'') as answer
FROM questions AS q
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT userid, questionid, MAX(id) AS maxid
     FROM questionanswerxref
     GROUP BY userid, questionid) AS maxids  -- find latest answerid 
ON maxids.questionid = q.id
LEFT JOIN questionanswerxref AS qq           -- then join to answer
on qq.id = maxids.maxid
WHERE qq.userid = :userid
ORDER BY q.id
```

Comment: Terje D, that seems to have worked. I had to change the on qq.id = maxids.id to on qq.id = maxids.maxid because it wasnt finding the column, to me it looks right, that change shouldn't affect anything right?

Comment: D, awesome, this worked good. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.